# Подскажите как реализовать такой эффект?

Tags: javascript

На изображении всё показано

[image: На изображении всё показано, помогите реализовать данный эффект]

Помогите реализовать данный эффект, может кто-то делал что-то похожее?

Я реализовал так. Но плавности не получается и не кроссбраузерно получается:

```js
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
  var course = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
  var top = parseInt($('.about_info-content-inner').css('top'));
  var height = parseInt($('.about_info-aerostat').css('height'));
  var right = parseInt($('.about_info-aerostat').css('right'));
  if (top == 0 || top < -185) {
    if (course > 0) {
      $('.about_info-content-inner').css({'top': 0});
    }
    else if (course < 0) {
      $('.about_info-content-inner').css({'top': -1});
    }
  }
  else if (top == -185) {
    if (course > 0) {
      $('.about_info-content-inner').css({'top': -184});
    }
    else if (course < 0) {
      $('.about_info-content-inner').css({'top': -185});
    }
  }
  else {
    if (course > 0) {
      $('.about_info-content-inner').css({'top': (top + 1)+'px'});
      $('.about_info-aerostat')
        .css({'height': (height + 1)+'px'})
        .css({'right': (right - 2)+'px'})
    }
    else if (course < 0) {
      $('.about_info-content-inner').css({'top': (top - 1)+'px'});
      $('.about_info-aerostat')
        .css({'height': (height - 1)+'px'})
        .css({'right': (right + 2)+'px'})
        .animate({opacity: .6}, 2500);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.layout_container {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.layout_header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 92px;
}

.layout_content {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.layout_footer {
  @include space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex: 0 0 76px;
  border-top: 1px solid darken($gray, 35%);
}

.about_info-title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: $gold;
  margin-top: 18rem;
  margin-left: 16.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.about_info-content {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: $white;
  width: 440px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-left: 17rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.about_info-content-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.about_info-aerostat {
  position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 500px;
  top: 10%;
  right: 20%;
}

.about_info-aerostat img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout_container">
  <div class="layout_header">
      header
  </div>
  <div class="layout_content">
    <div class="about_info">
      <div class="about_info-title">Content-title</div>
      <div class="about_info-content">
        <p class="about_info-content-inner">content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_info-aerostat">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="layout_footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [здесь](https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)
Это сайт одного из javascript плагинов для parallax скроллинга.
Существуют и другие библиотеки.

Очень простой пример применения для фона.

```js
skrollr.init({
  smoothScrolling: true,
  forceHeight: false
});
```

```css
#bg1 {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/150x150);
}

#skrollr-body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg1" data-0p="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100p="background-position:-500px -1000px;">
  <div id="skrollr-body">

  </div>
</div>
```